# Order table according to the order in another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have table **`B`** and table **`R`**, 
They are identical in their field definition.
Table R contains some of the items in B, ordered by a specific order (which is not related to any of the values)).

I want to select items from table B and have them ordered in the order in which they appear in table R.

Basically I need the result as `IQueryable<B>` - but if I simply try to select from R and cast as `IQueryable<B>` it throws an exception that I can't do that casting - so a different solution to achieve this is also acceptable.

Comment: Why not just order `B` by `R`, surely there are unique fields in `B/R` that you can use to order by using a predicate on Linq's `OrderBy`?

Comment: Iff Listov's Substitution Principle applies you should have B inherent R or vice versa.

Comment: You can also use .Select to map B onto R.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Func<R, B> r2b = r => new B { Id = r.Id, Description = r.Description};
var bs = Rs.Select(r => r2b(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by *order of table `R`*.

You say the two tables have identical objects. So if you want to consider only the items in table `R`, in that case would want to join them. If no match is found you get an empty sequence. Something like:

```
 var ordered = from    b in bs
               join    r in rs
               on      b equals r //since you said they are identical
               orderby r //or whatever R table is ordered with
               select  b;
```

If you want to merely get the sort order of table `R` (and provided the number of rows in both tables are equal), you can use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

```
var ordered  = bs.Zip(rs, (b, r) => new { b, r })
                 .OrderBy(x => x.r) //or whatever R table is ordered with
                 .Select(x = x.b);
```

**Edit:**

You have to specify on what basis the equality is defined in case of `Join`. Also on what basis the `R` table is ordered. You can specify it like:

```
 var ordered = from    b in bs
               join    r in rs
               on      b.Id equals r.Id //or whatever the equality is based on.
               orderby r.Id //or whatever R table is ordered with
               select  b;
```

If you wan't the entire fields to be checked for equality then you can do:

```
 var ordered = from    b in bs
               join    r in rs
               on      new { b.Id, b.Name } equals new { r.Id, r.Name }
               orderby r.Id 
               select  b;
```

Same goes for the `Zip` approach:

```
var ordered  = bs.Zip(rs, (b, r) => new { b, r })
                 .OrderBy(x => x.r.Id) //<- specify here
                 .Select(x = x.b);
```

If you want to merely get the rows for `R` as `B`, then Laurence's approach is what you have to go for.

Comment: I'm trying to use your first method.
It does not allow me to say "on r equals b"
(they are both identical tables in the sense that they have exactly the same fields - but they are two different tables - so Linq defines two different classes for them when I add them to the DBML - and it seems I cannot do any sort of castings between them).
there is an id field called bid - if I do on r.bid equals b.bid - it allows. Also, what is o? I suppose you meant r.
But - when I try it like this and run - I get an exception - 
"Cannot order by type 'r' :\

Comment: Second method yields the same exception.

Comment: @YuvalA. you're very close. Only minor adjustments needed. First decide on what basis is is `r` and `b` equal? is it based on id field? Or is it based on both `id` and `name` fields? So decide that. Secondly, you cannot order by `r` because it's not comparable (in other words doesnt implement `IComparable<T>`). You have to specify based on which field the ordering should be

Comment: The thing is - there is an identity field 'bid' - but I don't want to order by it (as it will order it numerically) - so I figured I need an extra field in R - that will simply contain a "row number" in ascending order (but not an identity because bid is the identity and there can be only one -I tried). So I did it inside the query that creates R (using 'SELECT *, 'order'=ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY NEWID()) - this creates a random order (which is the purpose of R) - the field name is 'order'.
However, now when I tell it orderby r.order - it still DOESN'T WORK:

Comment: It always returns in the same order - which to me seems like a descending 'bid'.
Could it be because B has no 'order' field...? I don't know.....

Comment: this is the query:
from b in Bs
join r in Rs on b.bid equals r.bid
orderby r.order
select b;

'order' exists for sure - and it does simply contains numbers in ascending order - this is the order I want the items to be returned - but they aren't...

Comment: @YuvalA. no, its not because `B` doesn't have an order field. What do you mean by doesn't work? Giving wrong order? Could you provide a sample input set (both `R` and `B`) and the output you want to get from it? That was its much easier for us.